# How I can migrate to Oracle 12c If I am using Hibernate 3.3 and spring-orm i.e spring-hibernate bootstrapping?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, oracle12c, spring-orm

We want to change our database to Oracle 12c 12.2.0.1 from Sybase.

We are currently using Hibernate 3.3 with Spring 4.3.22, We use spring hibernate bootstrapping mode to connect to database i.e `getHibernateTemplate()` which is having almost 150 occurrences.

After changing Hibernate properties and driver to ojdbc8-12.2.0.1_RHAS64 we found hibernate 3.3 does not provide dialect [`org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle12cDialect`] for Oracle 12c which is provided in Hibernate 5.XX version.

We were using `LocalSessionFactoryBean` as part of spring orm in XML `appCtxDaos.xml` so after upgrading to 5.3 we changed beans class references to `XX.XX.hibernate5.localSessionFactoryBean` from `XX.hibernate3.localSessionFactoryBean` which is setting up hibernate configuration for application [Point#1].

After moving to hibernate 5.3, When we checked alternative for `getHibernateTemplate()`, Hibernate community recommends to use plain Hibernate coding style ( `hibernate.cfg.xml` ).

We added `HibernateUtil.java` class which is setting up hibernate configuration for application ***[Point#2]***.

Moving ahead I will have to remove Point#1 spring-orm Hibernate configuration, But in our application there are 7-8 xml files which defines application flow and have cascading beans dependency for session Factory, datasource etc

Where database connectivity using ***point#2*** can be achieved but removing ***point#1*** and all dependencies is being challenge.

Please suggest what should be approach to move further to minimal changes in existing application ..

Any contribution to this problem really appreciated !!!

Comment: YOu are understanding the community wrong. Use Spring to configure the `SessionFactory` using the `LocalSessionFactoryBean`. Then just inject the `SessionFactory` and use `getCurrentSession` to get the Spring managed session. Don't start to go along the path of a `HibernateUtil` class. Also why not start with a change in DB only and use an older Oracle Dialect, then move your dao to the `SessionFactory` insteadof `HibernateTemplate` and finally upgrade Hibernate. You can still use an older dialect with Oracle12.

Comment: **_Thank you so much @Deinum..._**

This worked .... As of now we are able to configure hibernate successfully with change in DB only and using older Oracle dialect i.e `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect`.

Proceeding with moving our DAO to `SessionFactory` instead of `HiberanteTempalte()`, how this can be achieved as we are using spring xml based spring configuration for `LocalSessionFactoryBean` and SessionFactory can not be autowired.

we are getting exception :  `getHibernateTemplate().get()` i.e `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not load an entity:`

Comment: why wouldn't you be able to auto wire the `SessionFactory`?

Comment: As we are not using annotation-based spring .. Would it be good progamming practice to add  `<context:annotation-config />` and accessing xml declared bean using 

@autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory; 

Reference in my DAO class, Please correct me If anything missing / wrong .. thank you

Comment: Then how did you configure you daos prior to this? You either injected a prepared `HibernateTemplate` or the individual `SessionFactory` instance. So not sure why it should change.

Comment: `<bean id="dbHibernateSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean" >
  <property name="dataSource" ref="IntraDayDbDataSource" />
  <property name="useTransactionAwareDataSource" value="true" />
  <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/hibernate-fut.cfg.xml" />
  <property name="hibernateProperties" ref="hibernateProps" />
 </bean>`





And while using this in my DAO we have `getHibernateTemplate().get();`

Comment: that is only the definition of the hibernate session factory it is not how it gets into your dao. But you are asking rather a different question than the original one.